# How to pass a function's parameter variable to a decorator?

Tags: python

I'm basically trying to track events in an API.
There are several routes with different functionalities.
I came with something like this:

```
# defining a decorator like this:
class tracker():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __call__(self, function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        async def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            self.save_event(*args, **kwargs)
            return await function(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated

    def save_event(self, *args, **kwargs):
        this_would_be_function_arg = self.data
        # do something with the data
        pass


# to be used like this:
@tracker(data=function_arg):
def my_func(function_arg):
    # something...
    pass
```

Is it possible? I know I could access from `kwargs`, but I won't always know whats being passed, and I don't need every single parameter, so I didn't want to get everything.

Comment: Do you want to pass string representation of function's parameter to decorator?

Comment: No, I want to pass whatever comes in to `function_arg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function signatures from the `inspect` module can help.

With a saved signature of the wrapped function, you can bind the arguments to it at every call and look them up by name regardless of type (arg or kwarg).

Docs: [introspecting callables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object)

```
import inspect
import functools

class tracker():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.signature = None

    def __call__(self, function):
        self.signature = inspect.signature(function)
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            bound = self.signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            bound.apply_defaults()
            self.save_event(bound.arguments[self.data])
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated

    def save_event(self, value):
        print(f"called with {self.data}={value}")

@tracker(data='function_arg')
def my_func(arg1, function_arg=None):
    pass

my_func(0,10)
my_func(10, function_arg=20)
my_func(-1)

# output:
# called with function_arg=10
# called with function_arg=20
# called with function_arg=None
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! Implementing is looking a bit weird though (the way I implemented), I wonder if that's the most efficient / well-designed way to do an event tracking system.

Comment: @lowercase00 I'm glad I could help. Regarding the design, only you see the full picture. It is quite subjective, but a programmer usually feels during his work if all the pieces fit together well or not.

Comment: Indeed, this is the kind of implementation I'm not totally happy about. I'm trying to track all events all my system (user logged in, user create X , user delete Y, etc). It seems that there's a high variation of where the data I need is (sometime a in `function_arg`, sometimes in an attribute of `function_arg`. Even though this looks clean at first sight, getting everything to work would require a lot of work arounds. I wonder if maybe I shouldn't just call a function with all the arguments I need and save the events to Mongo, I'll take the weekend to think about solutions.